# Use WCF as a foundation of a Socket/TCP client (or any better options?)

Tags: wcf, sockets, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a .NET client to talk to a server written in Java implemented with Netty framework. The server receives and sends back messages in predefined format. It's not a request/response protocal since messages receiving and sending are two irrelevant things.

I can write a raw client with Socket or TcpClient class but I'm thinking about using WCF as the infrastructure so I can focus on the message encoding/decoding and reuse most of the components in WCF.

I'm sure I have to write extensions for WCF but I don't know where to start. I can find some samples with request/response communication patterns but what I need is something like sending and receiving data separately like programming with Netty (or even raw TcpClient or Socket) - with a single TCP connection.

So my question is, where should a I start with WCF? Any samples or resources for me? Is WCF a good choice for this task and are there any better options?